# Laravel 5 fetching database rows recursively for autocomplete

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `locations` database table that has the following fields: `id, name, parent_id`. It will store data such as: `"1, Canada, 0"`, `"2, Ontario, 1"`, `"3, Toronto, 2"`, etc.

I have an autocomplete text box that I'd like to be populated with "Toronto, Ontario, Canada" when the user begins typing something such as "Tor" into the text box.

My current approach in Laravel 5 is the following. I'm sure it's not the best approach. What's the best way to fetch this hierarchical data from the `locations` table in Laravel?

```
    public function getAutocomplete(Request $request)
    {
        $term = $request['term'];

        $results = array();

        $queries = Location::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->get();

        foreach ($queries as $query) {
            if ($query->parent_id != 0) {
                $parent = Location::where('id', '=', $query->parent_id)->first();
                if($parent->parent_id != 0) {
                    $grand_parent = Location::where('id', '=', $parent->parent_id)->first();
                    $results[] = ['id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->name . ", " . $parent->name . ", " . $grand_parent->name];
                }
                else {
                    $results[] = ['id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->name . ", " . $parent->name];
                }
            } else {
                $results[] = ['id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->name];

            }
        }

        return response()->json($results);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try `select2` (https://select2.github.io/)?

Comment: Using recursive partials with @each in Laravel & Blade helped me out. See the following article: https://www.sitepoint.com/laravel-blade-recursive-partials/